# How can I insert a record using Form Builder and PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, formbuilder, ora-01400

I'm slowly learning SQL and how to use form builder 6. The situation is I have a simple table named 'players' within the table I have three columns:

- player_no (primary key)
- position
- goals

Within form builder 6 I have created a very simple form using these three fields. The form is named 'TEAM'. At at the foot of the form I have a button labelled 'Add'. The goal is for the user to enter a player_no, position and goals and then to click 'Add'. This information is then to go into my table.

All attempts so far have failed miserably. I have set up a trigger on the button (WHEN_MOUSE_CLICK). I have then entered the following code:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO players ( player_no )
  VALUES ( :TEAM.player_no )
END
```

For the purpose of testing it out I have only been using the one (player_no) field. This then compiles with no errors yet when I run the form and enter a player_no and hit the button I get the following error in the status bar:

frm-40735: WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-01400

Am I doing something horribly wrong? I am very much new to SQL and Form Builder so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ORA-01400: cannot insert Null](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01400.php) seems like one of your fields are not null and you omited them on insert. or value :TEAM.player_no is null during insert.

Also, somewhere from web:

> FRM-40735: ON-INSERT trigger raised
>   unhandled We have had similar problem
>   since 11.5.9. We clear Jinitiator
>   cache, and temporary internet files
>   (tools>internet options then under
>   temporary internet files the clear
>   files button). Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of using Form Builder is that you almost always *don't* need to write the DML statements yourself.

Just make the block based on the table - then the user can add and modify as many records as they like, then when they save (i.e. COMMIT), the Forms runtime automatically works out what INSERTs and UPDATEs are required to save the changes.